# Benefits/Drawbacks of using pseudo elements (:after, :before) vs. padding/background positioning?

Tags: html, css, background, pseudo-element, css-content

I'm digging through some older code on a site that I'm working with, which uses **[iconize](http://pooliestudios.com/projects/iconize/).** The way that it seems to work is by adding a class like this...

```css
a[href=$='.pdf']{
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 0;
    background: transparent url('icon.gif') no-repeat center right;
}
```

Is there any benefit to doing it that way than the way that I'd have done it? Something like this...

```css
a[href=$='.pdf']:after{
    content: url('icon.gif');
    vertical-align: sub;
}
```

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate both of them...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBN5f/2/)

My question is... What are the benefits, if any, of using pseudo-elements vs. standard padding and background positioning for appending/prepending images to elements?

Comment: @Lucas: That is incorrect. [Pseudo-elements are put _inside_ the element](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pseudo-element/info) before or after the _content_ of that element.

Comment: @ScottS, thanks, i missed that...

Comment: I was partly responsible for this question, and wanted to add my codepen http://cdpn.io/Fwqlp which highlights why I like the padding/background method over the pseudo element method. To facilitate both left and right aligned icons, you must copy the url element all over and possibly waste lines reversing the :after or :before you didn't want later.

Comment: @EHLOVader: I've addressed your concern in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a few initial and later thoughts. I may still think of some more to add.

### Padding/Background

**Advantage(s):**

1. Works for IE6-7 (i.e. older browsers).
2. If one wanted to overlap the icon with the text, [especially if centered](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBN5f/9/), this would be easier to implement.

**Disadvantage(s):**

1. More thought needed to implement (must calculate some factors).
2. For older browsers, only one background was supported, so if another background was needed, then there was a conflict to be resolved.
3. If browser is set to not print background images, then a "gap" for the padding will still exist in the printed text, but no image will be there. This could be resolved through print media css.

### Pseudo-Elements

**Advantage(s):**

1. Easier to implement (no calculations needed).
2. [It can have its own `padding`, `border`, `opacity`, etc. applied if desired](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBN5f/4/), just as if it were a real element.
3. Related to #2, it can actually be [moved outside the element](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBN5f/6/) if needed or desired.
4. Semantically, it is being implemented in a more appropriate manner. The icon is not really a "background," but neither is it an essential part of the html that a content `img` might be, so the pseudo-element fits the bill for enhancing the presentation, but not causing issues if it is missing (in older browsers).
5. In CSS3 browsers (and possibly CSS2), usually less code can be used to switch between right or left aligned icons (see "Discussion about code length" below).

**Disadvantage(s):**

1. Only one (of each type) allowed per element, so if it is needed for something else on an element, then you can have conflict.
2. Not supported in older browsers.
3. Some elements ([replaced elements](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pseudo-element/info)) cannot take pseudo-elements, so this would not even be an option.

### Discussion about code length

[EHLOVader](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704765/ehlovader) noted in a comment to the question that part of his concern was extra coding that might be needed for pseudo-elements as opposed to background/padding if one wanted to switch to a left side icon. He gave [this codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/full/Fwqlp). However, it can be made to be less code to do a pseudo-element. Assuming `.iconleft` is a class used to put the icon left rather than right, and `.iconit` the class that sets an icon at all, then the following code concisely makes it happen **for CSS3 browsers** using the `:not()` selector ([here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBN5f/11/), using the original `.pseudo` class of the OP for iconing):

```
.iconit:not(.iconleft):after,
.iconit.iconleft:before {
    content: url('http://www.jasonapollovoss.com/web/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/pdf_icon_small.png');
    vertical-align: sub;
}
```

The same could be done **with CSS2 browsers** if an `iconright` class is used to explicitly set an icon to the right, or `iconleft` to the left (no `iconit` class needed then):

```
.iconright:after,
.iconleft:before {
    content: url('http://www.jasonapollovoss.com/web/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/pdf_icon_small.png');
    vertical-align: sub;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that update, I like the way that can be done with the single content on both. It hadn't crossed my mind to do that. I also like how compatibility wise (as browsers go) the background works for more. If this solution were in a library as it were it would be great. But to modify pseudo elements from one CSS in another to use :before instead would be somewhat complicated. Such would be the case if poolie's iconizer had used :after instead of the backgrounds.

Comment: @EHLOVader: Thank you for your comment. Modifying code was not a condition of the question. The question dealt with advantages/disadvantages between the two methods. Obviously, if something was already implemented in a certain way, there can be challenges to modifying it, but that seems to be beyond the scope of the question. The OP is working with older code using the background method, so yes, it is going to be some work to change it over to pseudo-elements if that is decided. But that is not an inherent advantage/disadvantage to the two methods.

Answer (score 0):

What makes pseudo-classes so useful is that they allow you to style content dynamically. In the  example above, we are able to describe how links are styled when the user interacts with them. As we’ll see, the new pseudo-classes allow us to dynamically style content based on its position in the document or its state
Read more http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/30/how-to-use-css3-pseudo-classes/